# When is the best time to setCurrentItem of ViewPager after activity starts?

Tags: android, animation, android-viewpager

I want my viewPager to slide to the assigned index after my activity finish it's onCreate etc.. work. I want to get a smooth animation. I will get the current index from previous activity.
Kindly suggest in which function should i write viewPager.setCurrentIndex(index) to acheive this. or How to achieve this?

Comment: You could try posting a runnable that changes the current item to the `ViewPager` message queue, using [`post()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

Answer (score 1):

To be sure, that you will not catch exception, you can do:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements Runnable
{
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private static final long DELAY = 50; //For example

    private static final int initItem = 10;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
       ...
       //Setting ViewPager and stuff
       ...
       mHandler.postDelayed(this, DELAY);
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        if(mViewPager.getChildCount() == 0)
            mHandler.postDelayed(this,DELAY);
        else
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(initItem, false); //Set true if need smooth animation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it after setAdapter();

Comment: Two Problems: 1. Unable to see ViewPage Title Strip. 2. unable to get slide animation.

Answer (score 0):

After set adapter...

And override getPageTitle on your PagerAdapter

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#getPageTitle(int)

And

http://blog.pboos.ch/android-pagertabstrip-viewpager/